# Split a string in scala based on string lengths

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with two columns, one is an id and the other a value. My value column contains 1488 characters. I have to split this column into multiple rows with 12 characters each. Example:

Dataframe:

```
ID  Value
 1  123456789987653ABCDEFGHI
```

Expected output:

```
ID  Value
1   123456789987
1   653ABCDEFGHI
```

How can this be done in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `UDF` to split a string into equal length parts using `grouped`. Then use `explode` on the resulting list of string to flatten it.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def splitOnLength(len: Int) = udf((str: String) => {
  str.grouped(len).toSeq
})

df.withColumn("Value", explode(splitOnString(12)($"Value")))
```